# TypeScript type for MapboxGLjs React ref hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to add a source for my mapboxgl map which I am writing in React with hooks and TypeScript.

```
export default function App() {
  const mapContainer = React.useRef<any>(null);
   const map = React.useRef<any>(null);
   const [lng, setLng] = React.useState(-74.0632);
   const [lat, setLat] = React.useState(40.7346); 
   const [zoom, setZoom] = React.useState(12);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (map.current) return; // initialize map only once
    map.current = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapContainer.current,
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [lng, lat],
      zoom: zoom
    });
    map.addSource('property-data', {
      type: 'geojson',
      data: 'path/to/data.geojson'
    });
    
  });
```

I am encountering the following error:

> Property 'addSource' does not exist on type 'MutableRefObject'

What type then should I use if not any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to keep a `mapboxgl.Map` in the ref, and you also want it to be `null` before it's initialized. So that means your ref type is:

```
const map = React.useRef<mapboxgl.Map | null>(null);
```

This is good to fix (it's good to eliminate all uses of `any`), but that has nothing to do with the error you are getting.

When you have a ref, you *always* access what it's referencing via the `current` property.  So you simply need to change your last lines to this:

```
map.current.addSource(/* ... */)
```

[Working example playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#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)

Comment: Alex coming to my rescue again. I caught that “current” mistake shortly after posting.  Thanks for your help again, Alex!